# Clicking on Insert link for General link field is not showing child items

Tags: content-editor

When "Insert link" option is clicked for any field of type General link, the popup is showing only sitecore item and not showing the child items.

[image]

Is this because sitecore has to load lot of items ?
I tried setting datasource for some field in template it works fine but is there any global solution as it is difficult to update datasource for each field.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88001/discussion-on-question-by-dheeraj-p-clicking-on-insert-link-for-general-link-fie).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got this Issue resolved. Posting the answer here incase someone face similar issue.

We had a custom processor to prevent resolving items without version and then it will redirect to '404 Not Found' error Page. This was impacting content editor features also.
So we disabled this processor and enabled the out of the box 'enforceVersionPresence' setting on the site node.

enforceVersionPresence : If set to true, '404 Not Found' error page will be shown if the context item does not have a requested version.
Default value is false.

Comment: Some time ago I also faced with the same issue. And what do you think, it was also wrong processor! Hope, this will be helpful for others: first review custom processors in httpRequestBegin and others commonly used pipeline.